# Site not reachable zalenium with docker-compose

Tags: selenium, docker, ddev, zalenium

I have zalenium integrated to a docker-compose file where I have several sites and these are accessed through a router in Nginx, when when I make the request to a specific site, it appears to me that it is not treatable if I enter the Zalenium container and I execute curl against the URL "base.local.site", this returns the correct HTML, the same for curl "other.local.site".

I need to do a javascript tests on these sites independently(One at a time not at the same time), so when I run the test with zalenium, I get the message that the site is not reachable.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried several things for example:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  #--------------#
  zalenium_desa:
    image: "dosel/zalenium"
    container_name: zalenium_desa
    #hostname: zalenium_desa
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    ports:
      - 4445:4444
    command: >
      start --desiredContainers 2
            --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 8
            --screenWidth 800 --screenHeight 600
            --timeZone "America/Montevideo"
            --videoRecordingEnabled true
            --sauceLabsEnabled false
            --browserStackEnabled false
            --testingBotEnabled false
            --cbtEnabled false
            --lambdaTestEnabled false
            --startTunnel true
    environment:
      - HOST_UID
      - HOST_GID
      - SAUCE_USERNAME
      - SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY
      - BROWSER_STACK_USER
      - BROWSER_STACK_KEY
      - TESTINGBOT_KEY
      - TESTINGBOT_SECRET
      - CBT_USERNAME
      - CBT_AUTHKEY
      - LT_USERNAME
      - LT_ACCESS_KEY
    external_links:
    - "ddev-router:base.ddev.site"
    - "ddev-router:other.ddev.site"
```

Do you have any idea what might be happening?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGaFI.png

Comment: What happens if you just start the docker-compose stack, not run tests, and go through VNC into the container, open the browser manually and try to load the site?

Comment: The browser is only accessible when a connection is made, I don't see how to interact from the VNC without first having a connection.

Comment: If you have a running container, you can access the live view and proceed to interact manually with the container.

Comment: Hello, I can't find a way to use the browser manually, I have the containers and I see the preview live, but only the zalenium logo appears on the integrated VNC, how can I enter it manually? Do you have any reference or documentation to guide me?

Comment: There should be a link that says "interact via VNC", please click on it and you should be good to start using the container. You can do right click to get the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

To make the site reachable in your config, you can add

```
    external_links:
    - "ddev-router:<project>.ddev.site"
```